# Convert CSV file to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have CSV files that need converting to XML, but the problem is, is that I only need certain fields and the number of lines changes.

I'm new to XSLT and can't figure out how to convert this CSV to XML especially as the CSV files have different row/line counts.

<strike>Pastebin link to the issue: https://pastebin.com/AfRxRRJX</strike>

For example:

Example input data looks like:

```
1,12345,7654321,1,08/08/19,08/08/19
2,12345,12345678,3
2,12345,22345679,7
2,12345,32345680,6
2,12345,42345681,2
3,12345,
```

What the data looks like from a human perspective:

```
First line, ID, accountNo, ???, orderDate, orderDate
Product row, ID, productCode, quantity
Product row, ID, productCode, quantity
Product row, ID, productCode, quantity
Product row, ID, productCode, quantity
Last Line, ID,
```

Output should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<orders>
    <order accountNo="7654321" orderDate="08/08/19">
        <orderItems>
            <orderItem productCode="12345678" quantity="3"/>
            <orderItem productCode="22345679" quantity="7"/>
            <orderItem productCode="32345680" quantity="6"/>
            <orderItem productCode="42345681" quantity="2"/>
        </orderItems>
    </order>
</orders>
```

I have tried putting together different snippets of XSLT code, but it always comes out as junk after the transformation.

================================================================================

I did but, unfortunately, I need first convert CSV to XML and then convert XML to XML formatting! '

```
<xsl:param name="csv-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'utf-8'"/>
<xsl:param name="csv-uri" as="xs:string" select="'file:///D:/csv%20to%20xml/example1.dat'"/>

<xsl:template match="/" name="csv2xml">
    <orders>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($csv-uri, $csv-encoding)">
                <order>
                 <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($csv-uri, $csv-encoding)" />
                 <xsl:variable name="order-info" as="xs:string*">
                     <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                         <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                             <xsl:if test="starts-with(., '1')">
                                 <xsl:copy-of select="tokenize(.,',')"/>
                             </xsl:if>
                         </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                     </xsl:analyze-string>
                 </xsl:variable>
                 <xsl:attribute name="accountNo">
                     <xsl:value-of select="$order-info[3]"/>
                 </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="orderDate">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$order-info[5]"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                 <orderItems>
                     <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                         <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                             <xsl:if test="starts-with(., '2')">
                                 <orderItem>
                                     <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
                                         <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                                         <xsl:if test="$pos=3">
                                             <xsl:attribute name="productCode">
                                                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                             </xsl:attribute>    
                                         </xsl:if>
                                         <xsl:if test="$pos=4">
                                             <xsl:attribute name="quantity">
                                                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                             </xsl:attribute>    
                                         </xsl:if>
                                     </xsl:for-each>
                                 </orderItem>
                             </xsl:if>
                         </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                     </xsl:analyze-string>
                 </orderItems>
                </order>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <test>
                </test>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </orders>
</xsl:template>
```

'

Comment: What’s wrong as both your desired and result xml look the same.

Comment: I will try tomorrow night and I will post the code here for help. Many Thanks both!

Comment: This would be a very easy task or little bit more complex one depending the XSLT version you are targeting and the size of the input. This is because in XSLT 1.0 string processing must be done with recursion and in order to avoid stack overflow on big input sources the splitting task might be tricky. In XSLT 2+ you have `xsl:analyze-string` instruction with regexp.

Comment: I did but, unfortunately, I need first convert CSV to XML and then convert XML to XML formatting!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do simply something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize($csv, '&#10;')" />
    <orders>
        <xsl:variable name="line1-fields" select="tokenize($lines[1], ',')" />
        <order accountNo="{$line1-fields[3]}" orderDate="{$line1-fields[5]}">
            <orderItems>
                <xsl:for-each select="$lines[not(position() = (1, last()))]">
                    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="tokenize(., ',')" />
                    <orderItem productCode="{$fields[3]}" quantity="{$fields[4]}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </orderItems>
        </order>
    </orders>
</xsl:template>
```